# Why somethings don't show in friendly battles?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I noticed my base in Friendly Challenges doesn't look the same. I think it's an older version. For example there is no archer queen. Also if I move buildings around and immediately start another, there is no change. What is going on? How long does it take for changes to take affect to friendly battles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click challenge a layout selector inleft comes choose your layout from there. You have to Click "REPLACE LAYOUT" its on Picture of the current layout

Comment: Also I think you have to wait 24 hours before you can use a new layout.